# Make org-habit work with org-scheduled-past-days?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-habit

`org-habit` habits are `TODO` items `SCHEDULED` for some particular time/date.  If that date happens to be outside of the range of `org-scheduled-past-days`, the habit is not displayed in the agenda view for today's date.

I would like all habits to always appear under today's date (or something similar: for example, all habits that are not done today would also be OK).  Is that possible as things stand?

For bonus points, closely related I think: I would like the time of day that the habit is scheduled for to always be displayed (regardless of whether the habit is scheduled for today, or is a reminder of a habit that was scheduled for a day before today).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `org-habit-show-all-today` to non-`nil` will cause /all/ habits to appear in the agenda, even if the aren't scheduled that day.

Comment: This works but I realize after writing my question is not what I want: with this set, you do see habits that are done for that day, or didn't need doing that day in the first place.  There is an open patch on the emacs-orgmode list that does what I want ("org-habit: allow overriding org-scheduled-past-days and always including time of day")